# Angular 2 - Http - Properly Ignore Empty Results

Tags: http, angular2-services

I have quite a few REST end-points that process a request and simply return 200. I noticed it is an error to map the result with `json()`. If I try not to do any sort of mapping whatsoever, I see a browser warning that it could not parse XML. As returning nothing is pretty common, I am curious how I should be handling the response.

Here is a basic code example:

```
await this.http.put("/api/some_url", data).toPromise();
```

Here is the warning that shows up in Firefox:

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: http://localhost/api/some_url Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

If I try to map with `json()`, it blows up entirely. If I do nothing or try to map to `text()`, I just get the warning.

In all cases, the response headers contain `Content-Length: 0`, so I am surprised Angular2/Firefox is trying to parse anything. I don't know if this warning is coming from Angular2 or Firefox. I have tried this in Chrome and IE and there is no warning. So I am wondering if it is specific to Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

When no content is returned, e.g. `return Ok()` (HTTP status code 200) in ASP.NET Core, content-type is (naturally) not specified, but Firefox assumes the response to be XML and tries to parse an empty document, which results in the following console error:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location ...

Specifying `return NoContent();` (HTTP status code 204) makes Firefox happy (and also works for other browsers).

The issue is reported at [Bugzilla@Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=521301):

> and a parsing failure will simply be logged to the web console instead.